# How to change stylesheet of QMessageBox button?

Tags: c++, qt5, qmessagebox

I want to chanhe the background colour and font of QMessageBox button?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Information,
               "QMessageBox Background Color",
               "This is QMessageBox with Different Background Color");

    //Change background color
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Background, Qt::cyan);
    msgBox.setPalette(palette);

    //Change font
    QFont font( "Tokyo" );
    font.setPointSize( 32 );
    font.setWeight( QFont::Bold );
    font.setItalic( TRUE );
    msg->setFont(font);

    msg->exec();

    msgBox.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

For more on stylesheet http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html

Comment: @dilipyadav If it works, can you please mark it as answer ?

Comment: what is msg in msg->exec(); ??